# Updateing Gridview Via Timer

Tags: asp.net, gridview, timer

I'm trying to update a gridview via a timer, so taht no timeout for the page itself  occurs.What I tried in this case is to do a ping and do it every few seconds and add the result to the gridview.

What I'm managing is only a 2 line gridview (thus 2 entries at max). all other content is....."refreshed". What I tried is the following below (current version). I even tried it to put the timer into the updatepanel in addition to the gridview....or leave the gridview out of the panel while the timer is in (last version there had the timer working but the gridview did not change at all).

**Code Behind:**

```
public partial class Ping : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private int _MaxPings = 100;
    private DataTable _PingResults = new DataTable();
    private string _Url = "127.0.0.1";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _PingResults.Columns.Add("Time");
        _PingResults.Columns.Add("Result");
        UI_PingResult.DataSource = _PingResults;
        UI_PingResult.DataBind();

        AddToPingResult(_Url);

    }

    public void AddToPingResult(string IP)
    {
        Process pingProcess = new Process();
        int secondsWaited = 0;
        ProcessStartInfo pingProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("ping ");


        if (_PingResults.Rows.Count >= _MaxPings)
        {
            _PingResults.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        pingProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "-n 1 " + IP;
        pingProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        pingProcessStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
        pingProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pingProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        pingProcess.StartInfo = pingProcessStartInfo;
        pingProcess.Start();

        while (!pingProcess.HasExited && secondsWaited <= 10) // 10 Seconds
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            secondsWaited++;
        }

        if (pingProcess.HasExited)
        {
            string resultText = String.Empty;
            int linesRead = 0;

            while (!pingProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream && linesRead < 3)
            {
                string outputLine = pingProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine().Trim();

                if (linesRead == 2)
                {
                    resultText += outputLine + "<br />";
                }

                linesRead++;
            }

            _PingResults.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now, resultText);

        }

        UI_PingResult.DataBind();
    }

    protected void UI_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddToPingResult(_Url);
    }
}
```

**Html:**

```
<asp:Timer runat="server" ID="UI_Timer" Interval="6000" OnTick="UI_Timer_Tick"></asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UI_Timer" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="UI_PingResult" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Zeitpunkt" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Result" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="Resultat" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My question is now: What am I doing wrong here? Thus what do I need to do in order to be able to add to the gridview via the timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a Timer to "add" something to a Control like a GridView, you need to store the previous values somewhere otherwise they will be lost when adding data in the next Timer Tick. If you want to persist the data across pages or page refresh, use a `Session` instead of `ViewState`. See the example below.

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create a new table to hold the data
    DataTable table;

    //check if the viewstate item exists and if not create a new table
    if (ViewState["TimerTable"] == null)
    {
        table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("TimeStamp", typeof(DateTime));

        //create the viewstate object
        ViewState["TimerTable"] = table;
    }
    else
    {
        //the viewstate exists so you can cast it back to a datatable
        table = ViewState["TimerTable"] as DataTable;
    }

    //add the next tick data to the table
    table.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now);

    //rebind all the datat to the gridview
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

ASPX

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>

        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="2500"></asp:Timer>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```